# Incremental synthesis with yosys

Tags: scripting, verilog, synthesis, yosys

For a multi-file Verilog project using Yosys for synthesis, the script would generally look something like the following:

```bash
# read the all files
read_verilog *.v

# synthesis
synth -top
    
# output the synthesis result
write_verilog res.v
```

If a file is modified, the script must be rerun, triggering the synthesis of all files. This process becomes time-consuming, especially for larger projects. Does Yosys offer any methods to support incremental synthesis, allowing re-synthesis only for the modified file? If so, could you please provide specific script details with examples? In other words, suppose there are three files. For the initial synthesis, all three files are synthesized. If we later modify one file, how can Yosys be used to synthesize only the modified files?

If Yosys does not support incremental logic synthesis, are there other tools that can accomplish this?

In the scenario where module m1 instantiates m2 (located in different files), if modifications are made to m2, is it correct to infer that both m1 and m2 would need to undergo re-synthesis?

Does the outcome of logic synthesis will eventually yield a singular netlist file?

Comment: Yosys doesn't have built-in support for incremental logic synthesis and if any file is modified, the entire synthesis process needs to be rerun. But you can use custom scripts (such as Git with make file) to determine which files have been modified and selectively rerun synthesis only for those files.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, and I have two additional inquiries.    Firstly, in the scenario where module m1 instantiates m2 (located in different files), if modifications are made to m2, is it correct to infer that both m1 and m2 would need to undergo re-synthesis?
Furthermore, I've observed that yosys's final output appears to be directed to a single file.    Does this imply that, irrespective of the number of files within a project, the outcome of logic synthesis will eventually yield a singular netlist file?

Comment: Firstly, in typical hardware description language (HDL) flows, if you make modifications to a submodule (m2 in this case) that is instantiated in another module (m1), it does not necessarily mean that both m1 and m2 need to undergo re-synthesis.

The re-synthesis requirement depends on the nature of the modifications you made and how those changes affect the interfaces and functionality of the submodule and its usage in the parent module.

Comment: Secondly, the outcome of synthesis is always a single netlist. But we are not bound to do  this, as synthesis can be done for each module separately and then all modules are combined to make the final netlist. And this is also the basic idea behind the incremental synthesis that synthesis each module to create their netlist and then combine them to make the final netlist.

Comment: But mostly, I have seen that,  it is the case that we do not need to do synthesis of bottom modules, in incremental synthesis.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  Regarding your second point, can I understand it as incremental synthesis generally does not expand instantiation statements (similar to the absence of the 'flatten' command in Yosys)?

Comment: For instance, suppose m2 only contains the statement 'assign out = a & b;', and m1 contains 'm2 m2_0(a1, b1, out1);' After full synthesis (using "flatten"), m1 becomes 'assign out1 = a1 & b1'.  In this case, modifying m2 would necessitate the re-synthesis of both m1 and m2.  However, if after full synthesis (without "flatten"), m1 remains 'm2 m2_0(a1, b1, out1),' the modification of m2 only triggers the re-synthesis of m2 itself.  Perhaps my question seems somewhat basic;

Comment: I find myself a bit confused about whether traditional incremental logic synthesis processes involve flattening or not.

Answer (score 0):

Incremental synthesis works by synthesizing each module separately in the first run and in case of modification (subsequent runs), only the modified modules are synthesized. During incremental synthesis, each module is synthesized to create netlist and then all the netlist are assemble to make one final netlist i.e. the final synthesized design.

But, Yosys doesn't have built-in support for incremental logic synthesis and if any file is modified, the entire synthesis process needs to be rerun. Alternatively, you can use custom scripts (such as Git with make file) to determine which files have been modified and selectively rerun synthesis only for those files.